# Why my 3d applications lag when the administrator mode is not enabled?

Tags: windows, lag, 3d

I would like to understand why most of my 3d applications get huge lag spikes when I move the mouse and why this issue disappears after launching these applications as administrator.

This issue happens even after restarting Windows (8 or 10) and with few applications opened, although it's getting worse over time.

Comment: While I have to admit I don't know about the problem at all, what graphics card/driver do you use? And can you give an example of 3rd party applications where this happens, so we can tell what framework they use?

Comment: My graphic card is an AMD R9 270X with all drivers up to date. I can't remember all applications but recently it happens widely to Shadow Warrior 2013 and Europa Universalis 4 (video games).